# How to catching hibernate errors with spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, error-handling

Sorry if the questions have already been asked, but I can't find a correct answer.
I'm using Hibernate and Spring in my project and I want to catch and deal with hibernate exceptions if they happened. I've read that Spring could help me with it, but I don't really understand the documentation.

Spring seems to translate these exceptions into others Exceptions but I can't find in which ones to be sure to catch them all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is in the Spring page the tutorial about [handling exeptions](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc).

You can invoque the exception by throwing it when an error occurs:

```
throw new MyHibernateException(id);
```

Here is your custom exception:

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
public class MyHibernateException extends RuntimeException { }
```

You can set a face to your exception in the `web.xml`:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/views/errors/404.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```